# Should a referencing column be restricted to a single table?

Tags: mysql, optimization, schema, reference

I'm working on a project, and we've been creating tables that store references as a combination of two columns.

An example: we have an 'alerts' table, that is used to deliver information to the user.  An alert can refer to a number of different things, you can be alerted about a new message, or if another user has mentioned you.  These alerts have different types, and reference different types of data.  The message alert should direct the user to the message page, and the mention alert should direct the user to the other users page.

We're using columns alert.type and alert.article and storing type = MESSAGE or type = MENTION and article as the foreign key to *either* the message or user table.  This strikes me as sort of poor design, squishing references to two different tables into the same column.  However, since our tables are InnoDB I've had a tough time justifying this.  Hopefully I can get some expert input as to why this is a good/bad choice.  I'm thinking this approach could get into problems with indexed joins, but I really don't know enough about that.

I guess the other options are a column per type, which makes the table quite wide, and full of nulls, which I don't really mind, but some find tedious; or a 'child' table for each type which seems the most correct, but a bit overkill?

Cheers,

Comment: I agree with your assessment: the current variable-reference makes it impossible to use real foreign keys which is a deal-breaker for me. Either two optional foreign key columns, or two join tables is fine IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few reasons:

1. you can't use foreign keys, as said before.
2. you can't use a unique index (since the message/user id might be duplicated in the table, which means you can have duplicate message_ids too...)
3. you have to explain it to everyone

"Full of nulls"?  Cute.  Besides, it would only be 1/2 full of nulls (one column would always have a value).